# Reference & replace value in cell with value in range in google spreadsheet

Tags: replace, reference, google-sheets, find

I'm trying to do something which should be fairly trivial in Google Spreadsheet: I have a database of people in one sheet defined by "ID" and "Label" where the ID is a consecutive number and Label is the Name Surname of each person.

I'd need to be able, in a different sheet, to allow my team to type in the "Label" of a person and have the adjacent cell to show up the corresponding ID.

Given that sheet 1 is something like:
ID    Label
01    Alice Johnson
02    Bert Junger
03    Carlos Lopez

I would like that in sheet 2 would happen something like:
person = raw_input()
if(person == exist in sheet 1): 
get person's col and row from sheet 1
return value(person's col-1, person's row)

Ideally, I'm looking to do this only with google spreadsheets formulae, since it would be otherwise hard for my colleagues to be able to work on it.

Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an Index Match formula or V Lookup.. Have a look at [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/nairongschool.com/spreadsheets/d/1ScJ5yv512rtR6DxudtVzjBJM9_L5tTt5ak54aww3TNc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hey @James-donellan thank you so much! I'd need access to your spreadsheet, thanks!

Comment: fantastic. Thank you so much, very elegant solution!